# Which iTunes user can upload binaries?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have to give to a contractor the access to our iTunes account. He has to upload the binaries for iOS app and to send it for the review. He will upload the binaries from the XCode directly.

Which iTunes role should I give him? Technical maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technical is correct. As you can see in the image below, a technical user has read/write capabilities in the "Manage Your Applications" section of iTunes connect, as illustrated by the green "check". Admin, and legal will work as well.

[image]